# Is this op amp circuit a promising idea to measure 300VAC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I need to measure 300VAC. I am using the following circuit and it is working good. In the circuit, I am using 2mA/2mA current transformer. More details about this transformer are available [here](https://www.micro-transformer.com/2ma-2ma-voltage-transformer-ZMPT101C.html).
[image: Measuring a 300VAC, 60Hz using 2 power modules]

However, I want to use only one power source of 3.3V to reduce my PCB size and cost. Is the following circuit good? If it is not a workable solution, pelase suggest me what would be the better solution.

[image: Measuring 300VAC, 60Hz using only one supply voltage]

EDIT:

The transformer is a current transformer with `1:1` relation of `2mA/2mA`. Also, there is a limit of secondary resistance. The secondary resistance should be less than `100 ohms`. It is not a problem to short circuit the secondary. More details are available at the following link.

https://www.micro-transformer.com/2ma-2ma-voltage-transformer-ZMPT101C.html

If I use a voltage divider (solution suggested by `Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica`) as shown in the following circuit, the voltage swing at the output is little and hence, I cannot use the complete range of a microcontroller. So, I suppose the use of an operational amplifier is required.

[image: A solution with voltage divider]

Edit 2: Thanks to `Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica`, I understood several other mistakes in my previous circuits. Upon including `Kuba's` suggestions, I have the following circuit suggestion. Is it good to use a instrumentation amplifier to take full advantage of the microprocessor's ADC?

[image: Circuit with instrument amplifier]

Edit 3: I came up with another circuit which seems to work fine. Please give a look at it.

[image: Circuit with two op-amps]

Edit 4:
**Solution:**

Finally I am able to solve it. The following circuit is working good.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDfBsb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Where is the 300VAC coming from? There is no input protection so this would be a problem when measuring mains voltages.

Comment: @Kartman, around 255AC is the nominal voltage between lines. However, I am using a 300V to make sure even a slight increase in voltage could be measured. Also, I haven't worked on the protection part yet. Now I am working on the measuring part. Do you think varistor is sufficient as protection?

Comment: If you want to measure mains, use a mains metering ic. It does all the hard work for you.

Comment: @Kartman, I want to measure the voltage and see its waveform.

Comment: What is the transformer ratio?  Also, in words, what are you trying to do with the stepped down voltage?  As for safety, you need 2 types, overcurrent and overvoltage.

Comment: @user3425949, I am using a current transforme. Here the link to the transformer details. https://www.micro-transformer.com/2ma-2ma-voltage-transformer-ZMPT101C.html

Comment: @user3425949, I will update high voltage and high current protection. Thank you

Comment: @SKGadi See updates to my anwser.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, I updated my question with 2 more diagrams, please look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Re. Circuit #1

The op-amp is incorrectly biased.

#### Re. Circuit #2

1. Add a fuse! Assume that the rest of the circuit can fail shorted.
2. Accommodate the +10% high line condition by increasing the V-I resistor R1 to 165k ohm.
3. The gain is too high and the op-amp's output attempts to swing close to the rails. Recall that *the full transformer output current flows into the op-amp output*. After all, that's the only destination it can flow into! The op-amp won't be able to drive close to the rails at such a current. According to the [datasheet](http://www.gainchip.com/images/product/39_2.pdf), with a 2mA load the output can swing to about +/-0.4V away from the rails, i.e. between 0.35V and 2.95V:

   [image: The output voltage swing vs load current]

   The gain has to be decreased to lower the output voltage swing, i.e. the feedback resistor value has to be increased.
4. Add transient protection to the transformer secondary. Disconnecting the input will create an inductive kick that will overstress any load, be it an op-amp or an MCU.

#### Re. Circuit 3

The transformer is used as a *current* transformer, so the output current is exactly the input current. With a 150k V-I resistor at the input, the output current will be exactly 2mA across the recommended 50 ohm load. That's only 100mV RMS. The "+/-141mA peak" annotation is incorrect: the secondary current is 2mA RMS, maximum.

The voltage divider as shown further divides this small signal by half. At the very least, you'd want to move the divider to bias the winding, so that no amplitude would be lost:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqHIoX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output looks as follows:

[image: The output waveform of circuit #3 with a 50 ohm load]

### Discrete Current Source I-V Converter

If you can accommodate a slightly smaller output voltage range than the full 0 to 3.3V, then a current mirror would be another cheap solution for an I-V converter. The circuit below presents <100 Ohm load impedance to the transformer secondary. The output voltage at nominal line is 1.8Vpp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYfUio.png)</sup>

The output is shown below.

[image: The output waveform of the discrete I-V converter]

At volume, this probably costs <$0.25.

### Cheap Op-Amp I-V Converter

As for an op-amp: The good old LM358 and LM324 work with input and output down to ground, and will do the job straight from 24V supply, and is cheap. LM324 and LM358 have stock levels in millions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPl9qI.png)</sup>

For filtering the supply to the op-amp, it’s OK to use a simple RC filter.

The op-amp drives about 10Vpp through the 3k feedback resistor: that's 2mA RMS into the transformer secondary.

The output is then scaled down to fit into the 0.2-3.1V output range at nominal line voltage.

The op-amp can be any jellybean part not worse than LM358, ie. TL071, TL081, LM324, etc. With LM358 as shown, you have a second op-amp you could do something with.

[image: The output waveform of the op-amp I-V converter]

The output impedance of this circuit is about 1.35k ohm. The fault condition output current into the MCU pin would be 3mA peak if the output of the op-amp suddenly saturates at 20V. This fault current has a transient character, since the coupling is capacitive. So the op-amp failing with output shorted to either rail will not damage the MCU.

Comment: The circuit shown in the `Cheap Op-Amp I-V Converter` is the best and simplest, however, I see one problem. Again, it is because of my application specific problem. The `24VDC` comes from a battery and its voltage may change with time. Since 24 is taken as reference, my output may change. Is it possible to use `3.3V` source as reference to the positive pin? Also, are you considering that the op-amp LM358 is not rail-to-rail, so it may not reach zero?

Comment: I made an update based on your `Circuit 3`. I am using an instrument amplifier. Please look at it to see if it is a good solution.

Comment: I updated my question with Edit 2 and Edit 3. Please give your thoughts.

Comment: Impedance to secondary of transformer is greater than `50 ohms` for both *Discrete Current Source I-V Converter* and *Cheap Op-Amp I-V Converter*

Comment: @SKGadi LM358 in this application is swinging from about 6 to 16V, far from rail to rail. The output resistor network rescales it to 0-3.3V. The impedance to transformer secondary is virtual: a higher impedance is transformed into a lower one. You see that by looking at the current waveform coming out of the transformer. It’s close to zero ohms for LM358, and about 80 ohms for the discrete circuit. Ideal load for those transformers is 0 ohms, because they already have 150 ohms built-in resistance of the winding itself 50 ohms just adds to it.

Comment: LM358 and LM324 have input that goes past ground by 0.1-0.2V, and output that swings as close to zero as you want it with a pull-down. These circuits are can be simulated with a click. Please look at the waveforms, it literally takes a minute or less. You can easily virtually probe them in the simulator. That’s why I took time to ensure the simulations worked :) Your final solution will be destroyed by common spikes, you pretty much shorted the winding to op-amp input. Only low trace impedances will protect the op-amp, so design those for 1GHz bandwidth ESD spikes.

Comment: You don’t care about the offset much: the software takes a running average over 1 line cycle. The exact offset is not relevant as long as the signal remains unclipped. You can always lower the gain a bit. BTW, you’ll get a resolution way better than 8 bits in this measurement done right. You have to fit a sine wave to the data, and you’ll easily get 10 bits of amplitude resolution even with very simple code. If anything, some noise added to the signal would reduce nonlinearities of the ADC. Line inputs are usually plenty good at that already :)

Comment: Averaged over 10 seconds you can probably eke out 12 bits of amplitude in this application without trying too hard, and 16 bits of you use state of the art methods – when sampling is phase locked to line frequency. The phase lock can be closed in software, and you only need a digitally controlled oscillator chip to act as a sample clock for the ADC. Some MCUs offer that on-chip.

Comment: I updated **solution circuit** on my post by placing a `1k ohm` resistor and a `5.1 V` Zener diode to protect the `Op-amp`. Also I changed the Op-amp to `GS8331` for rail to rail compatibility. Is it good with the new changes?

Answer (score 3):

Absent the question of proper circuit protection, that should work **except** that you seem to be designing for 300V peak.  300VAC generally means 300V **RMS**; that, in turn, means about 425V peak -- your circuit, as drawn, will saturate.

When it *does* saturate, the op-amp will no longer be actively controlling the voltage at it's \$V_-\$ input -- you'll be forking that job onto the op-amp's protection diodes, or otherwise whatever circuitry happens to be there.

Moreover, while the thing is advertised to have a 20mA output, it doesn't specify how well it works at that much output current.

If I were to use the same front-end (\$150 \mathrm k \Omega\$ resistor and that current transformer), I would terminate the current transformer with a passive resistor to ground.  Then I would use the op-amp as a plain old voltage buffer, probably with higher resistances so the output is only loaded with \$10\mathrm k \Omega\$.

I haven't actually checked this circuit, and the coffee hasn't kicked in yet this morning -- feel free to analyze, simulate, and otherwise check it carefully before use.  It *should* give you a sine wave riding on 1.65V, scaled so that it stays within the rails when you've got a 300V RMS sinewave on the input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX00qK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi, I missed mentioning one important detail. The resistance connected to the secondary has a limit.  I updated it in the question. In this case it is 100 ohms. So, I don't want to move above 50 ohms to be safe.

Comment: You saved my life finding out that I made mistake considering RMS in the calculation of resistance. I will update that part.